# beginner to coding so posting question here

Tags: python-3.x

the question is Given an array A of length n. we need to create a new array B of length n-2 such that B[i] = max(A[i-1], A[i], A[i+1]) except from array A and n (1-based indexing) and return the new array, first and last element of array A has to excluded

```
def newArray(A):
    B = []
    for i in range(1, len(A)-2):
        B[i] = (max(A[i-1], A[i], A[i+1]))
return B
```

this is my approach but landed with no output

sample testcase:

input

```
A = [1,2,3]
```

output `3`

explanation: max(1,2,3) is 3 so answer is 3

Comment: Can you show an example with input A of length 5

Comment: Just to be clear, these are `list`s, *not* arrays.  Technically and fundamentally *very* different things.

Comment: Could you also show us how you call `newArray`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider utilizing [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and recognizing that you need to use `len(A) - 1` instead of `len(A) - 2` since the `stop` parameter for [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) is exclusive:

```
def new_array(A: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    B = []
    for i in range(1, len(A) - 1):
        B.append(max(A[i - 1], A[i], A[i + 1]))
    return B

print(f'{new_array([1, 2]) = }')
print(f'{new_array([1, 2, 3]) = }')
print(f'{new_array([1, 2, 3, 4]) = }')
print(f'{new_array([1, 2, 3, 2]) = }')
```

**Output:**

```
new_array([1, 2]) = []
new_array([1, 2, 3]) = [3]
new_array([1, 2, 3, 4]) = [3, 4]
new_array([1, 2, 3, 2]) = [3, 3]
```